# Can't open file 'menu.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a virtual environment in python3.5 and I've created many programs in that environment.

I activated the environment and executed one of my python programs using shell scripting (`.sh` file).

In that program, I have imported another program which is in the same env, but when I run the program I am not able to import it, and I get this error:

```
Can't open file 'menu.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error is saying it cannot find a _menu.py_ file. Does it exist?

Comment: provide your example code with the import as well please

Comment: If you do `ls .`, will you find your file?

Comment: When i am running the .py file the program works smoothly and the same program face issues when if executed on shell script

Comment: Check the path you given and also the imported files? For more details provide your sample code

Comment: For example : menu.py is my program   and  it is in an environment  "/home /pi /my_env ". in that program i imported other .py files too which exist in that same environment.      when i type "python3 menu.py" in the terminal i get the output.....i made another file "main_pgm.sh". in that file i have written "source my_env/bin/activate" , "python3 path of the program/menu.py". when i am running the script as "source main_pgm.sh" the menu.py file executed but i can't  import the other .py files and i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

As others said it is a bit difficult to determine your current setup but I think you need to add your root directory of your source code to PYTHONPATH. Use this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/root python3 menu.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank u for your comments..... i debugged the error.the problem was when i imported the other py files in the main program, i had not mention the path of the other program in the main program...  but thanks for the support...